# Undefined function uncaught by JSHint and JSLint

Tags: javascript, function, cookies, typeerror

Recently, I've been working on a cookie system for my website using JavaScript.  Now when I put them together, they refuse to run in Chrome's JavaScript console.

It says `TypeError: undefined is not a function` though everything seems be defined properly.

I have run this through JSLint and JSHint and they don't find any errors.

```
    //Date finder
    var day = new Date();
    day = day.substring(4, 100);

    //Pause function for later use
    function sleep(ms) {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (currentTime + ms >= new Date().getTime()) {
            alert("Please be patient while we connect...");
        }
    }

    //Sets cookie with cookie name, cookie value, and cookie expiry (converted into milliseconds by function)
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    //Uses a while loop to search through cookies outputed by "document.cookie" and find desired cookie
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    //Option to delete cookies if client desires
    function deleteCookie(del) {
        if (del == "Y") {
            var checkDel = confirm("Are you sure? Your username will be lost.");
            if (checkDel === false) {
                document.cookie = "username=; day";
            }
        }
    }

    //User input area - either uses cookie to identify user or requests user to input value
    function checkCookie() {
        var user = getCookie("username");
        if (user !== "") {
            alert("Welcome again " + user);
            var clearCookie = prompt("Do you wish to remove your cookie from this site?", "Y or N").toUpperCase();
            deleteCookie(clearCookie);
        } else {
            user = prompt("Please enter your name:").toUpperCase(0,1);
            if (user !== "" && user !== null) {
                setCookie("username", user, 91);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Please wait while we connect you to our servers.\nPress ENTER to initiate.");
    console.log("Logging onto system...");
    sleep(3800);
    console.log("User request: " + Math.floor(Math.random()*10000) + "; Server received request;        Connection accepted; " + day);
    checkCookie();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
var day = new Date();
day = day.substring(4, 100);
```

Dates in JavaScript are stored as objects which expose a number of functions, `substring` isn't one of them.

You can either use the `toString()` method on the date object like this:

```
day.toString().substring(4, 100);
```

Or you could use the `getDay()` method which returns the index of the date instance's weekday:

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'][day.getDay()-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

JSHint and JSLint only identifies syntax error. The error which you are receiving is run-time error occuring due to below reason

```
day.substring(4, 100);
/* day is Date object which does not have any property/method called 'substring'
 * therefore day.substring will be undefined
 * and using undefined as a function like undefined(...) will give you error- undefined is not a function
 */
```

Comment: JSHint also identifies other errors, such as warning about missing `break;` statements in switches, and missing radix parameters in `parseInt()`. But thanks for the info anyway.